# How to deal with a "useless" bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Let's consider this *simple* question: [How do I change where an image is when it is following my pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57189774/8620333). The asker is having an issue that got solved within few minutes in the comment section and a user gave the same answer that got accepted.

Recently I noticed a bounty added by the user who answered saying:

> This question has not received enough attention.

I don't know why he did this. The question was already solved (so it received enough attention) and technically we cannot expect a better answer since the solution is quite simple<sup>1</sup>.

That's why I think this bounty is "useless" since you cannot self award a bounty and I don't think we want someone to provide the same solution to get the bounty.

Should something be done in this case or the user is free to *waste* his reputation? I am more concerned about the fact that someone may simply abuse the bounty system to showcase his answers in order to get some *easy* upvotes. Is it legit if it's only for this purpose?

As a side note, the same user already did this before:

[jQuery not adding 'active' class to div when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56935442/8620333) (the bounty was removed I guess since the question was caused by a simple typo)

[Create a custom button plugin in Summernote](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53961843/8620333)

<sup>1: I can provide different ways to achieve the same goal like using `margin-left:4px`, `translateX(-4px)`, etc instead of `left - 4` but in my opinion it doesn't really deserve a new answer</sup>

Comment: He's paying to have the question and answer advertised. that's what all bounties are for.

Comment: @KevinB but we should *advertise* for a purpose, not to simply make a Q/A more visible, no? I don't like to see a Q/A in the bounty system where we are not expecting anything (expect when you want to reward someone)

Comment: The user knows (or at least should) that bounties aren't refunded and can't be self-awarded. There's certainly no guarantee that the user gets at least 10 upvotes on their answer, and I imagine that's actually quite unlikely. It's a risk/reward scenario. Now, what can be done about it? Nothing, unless the moderators are willing to remove a bounty and refund it.

Comment: See [“Abusing” bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit) and [Repeated use of bounties for promotional purposes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91814/134300)

Answer (score 12):

The bounty isn't *useless* as it's doing exactly what it says on the tin- er, the bounty reason: Drawing attention.

The answerer simply feels that the question, and by extension their answer, deserves or needs more attention. This is a perfectly legitimate tactic in that they are paying for advertising in the hopes that they get more upvotes for their answer.

It can backfire. It appears that you've found at least one case where it has for this user. And, yes, their bounty can go to waste, as they may receive little to no upvotes. That is their risk to take, however. Nothing wrong with it.

---

Alternatively, a better written answer could come along. Perhaps not in this case. (I haven't looked at the question at hand, so I will take your word for it.) If that happens, then it could end up winning the bounty if it receives enough votes itself. So, there is still incentive to check these bounties out and see if you can answer those questions better, if you're looking to snag the bounty rep.

Comment: *So, there is still incentive to check these bounties out and see if you can answer those questions better, if you're looking to snag the bounty rep.* --> That's why I am asking for this particular one as I don't think we can give a *better* answer (even if I know other alternative like I said in the question at the bottom). By the way; I wasn't aware that we can add a bounty to simply attract more views or get more upvotes.